# How to get alert for multiple pipelines success instead of 1 activity inside a pipeline in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, sql-azure-alerts

I am creating a new email notification alert for my azure data factory. So here i have 4 different pipelines with multiple data_copy activities each. As of now using Logic App i am able to send mail for each copy_activity of a pipeline. But my requirement is to get a single mail after successful completion of each pipeline.

Below is a basic understanding of current setup.

```
Pipeline A
    * Copy_Data Activity A1
    * Copy_Data Activity A2
    * Copy_Data Activity A3
Pipeline B
    * Copy_Data Activity B1
    * Copy_Data Activity B2
    * Copy_Data Activity B3
Pipeline C
    * Copy_Data Activity C1
    * Copy_Data Activity C2
    * Copy_Data Activity C3
```

Now my present work is that using logic App i can only send a mail for any Copy_Data activity e.g. Copy_Data Activity A1,A2,A3,C1, etc.

But my **expected result** in a mail using this Logic app is like below

```
Pipeline_Name       Status     
Pipeline A          Success
Pipeline B          Success
Pipeline C          Success
```

Basically i want the overall status of each pipeline as SUCCESS in a single mail if each and every activity of that pipeline is successful.

Any suggestions how to use logic app in fetching records on all pipeline levels instead of activity level.

I have successfully triggered the mail on copy_data activity level

> *Can't share any code here. Just to secure privacy*

I expect the results as SUCCESS/FAILED on pipeline level only.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the signal logic in the Data Factory's Monitoring Alerts, there are options for both pipeline level and activity level metrics.  Try changing from activity to pipeline.
[picture of Configure signal logic blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B0RB.png)